# Transitivity in Dafny

Tags: dafny

The following three assertions are taken out of their context, but shouldn't they hold from a logical point of view due to transitivity?

```
assert forall k: int :: start <= k <= m && k != p_i && k != i && 2*k+1 <= m ==> (heap_condition(p_a, k, m) <==> ((2*k <= m) ==> (p_a[(k)-1] >= p_a[(2*k)-1])) && ((2*k+1 <= m) ==> (p_a[(k)-1] >= p_a[(2*k+1)-1])));
assert forall k: int :: start <= k <= m && k != p_i && k != i && 2*k+1 <= m ==> heap_condition(p_a, k, m);
assert forall k: int :: start <= k <= m && k != p_i && k != i && 2*k+1 <= m ==> ((2*k <= m) ==> (p_a[(k)-1] >= p_a[(2*k)-1])) && ((2*k+1 <= m) ==> (p_a[(k)-1] >= p_a[(2*k+1)-1]));
```

The third assertion fails while the first two assertions hold.

The definition of `heap_condition` is as follows

```
predicate heap_condition(a: seq<int>, k: int, m: int)    
requires 1 <= |a|;
requires 1 <= k;
requires m <= |a|;
requires k <= m; 
{
        ((2*k <= m) ==> (a[(k)-1] >= a[(2*k)-1])) && ((2*k+1 <= m) ==> (a[(k)-1] >= a[(2*k+1)-1]))
}
```

In other words, the (supposedly correct) reasoning is

```
A ==> (B <==> C)  
A ==> B  
A ==> C
```

which does not seem to hold.

Comment: If assertions might not hold it might just mean Dafny could not prove them. You might have to supply proof elements. See this section in the Dafny reference to add proofs.
https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-verification-debugging

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Indeed, I had to break down the reasoning into smaller steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic regarding the `A`, `B`, and `C` is correct. Someone trying to prove `A ==> C` must first realize that knowing something about `B` will be useful, and this is where the creative juices of the Dafny verifier run out. The reason has to do with the quantifiers involved. I'll start with a solution and will then develop it into some explanations.

### A solution

If you just want to prove the conditions in the forms you have written them above, then you need to write a little bit of the proof of `A ==> C` yourself. In particular, you'll want to sneak in an assertion that mentions `B`, so that the verifier will think of using the two previous facts.

To get some space where you can "sneak in" some manual proof, use a `forall` statement. For your example, add the following `forall` statement just before the third assertion:

```
  forall k: int | start <= k <= m && k != p_i && k != i && 2*k+1 <= m
    ensures ((2*k <= m) ==> (p_a[(k)-1] >= p_a[(2*k)-1]))
    ensures ((2*k+1 <= m) ==> (p_a[(k)-1] >= p_a[(2*k+1)-1]))
  {
    assert heap_condition(p_a, k, m);
  }
```

This provides the part of the proof that the verifier didn't figure out by itself. The `forall` statement says to prove the two `ensures` clauses for any `k` in the given range (that is, the condition after the `|`). The proof is to first prove `heap_condition(p_a, k, m)` (which follows from the second assertion). After that, the verifier figures out the rest of the proof.

### An explanation

How could you figure this out and why does this work? When trying to prove the third assertion in your example, the conditions in the first two assertions are used as assumptions. In other words, the context of the third assertion assumes the quantifiers given in the first two assertions. Now, when the verifier assumes a `forall` expression, it mostly ignores it. *Unless* it has a reason to believe it may be useful in the proof.

For this reason, a quantifier needs to advertise to the verifier what might make the quantifier useful. This is done by a *matching pattern* aka a *trigger*. If you hover over the `forall` keyword in a quantifier, the tooltip that pops up shows you what trigger has been selected for the quantifier. In your case, the trigger for both the first and second quantifier is `heap_condition(p_a, k, m)`. This tells the verifier that the quantifier might be useful if the verification context includes some expression of the form `heap_condition(p_a, _, m)`, where I wrote `_` to denote any expression. Because your third assertion does not mention `heap_condition`, let alone `heap_condition(p_a, _, m)`, the first two quantifiers will not be used by the verifier when trying to prove the third assertion.

So, to prove the third assertion, you need to introduce a term `heap_condition(p_a, _, m)` where the `_` is the `k` from the last quantifier. The standard way to do that is to use a `forall` statement, like I did above.

Alright, so the `forall` statement can prove its two `ensures` clauses. It does that by first asking the verifier to prove `assert heap_condition(p_a, k, m)`. This assertion mentions an expression that matches the trigger of the (first and) second quantifier, and thus that quantifier gets instantiated with the given `k` in hopes that this might complete the proof. Indeed, this is exactly what is needed to prove the `assert` in the `forall` statement body. This asserted condition becomes part of the assumptions available when trying to prove the two `ensures` clauses. And since this expression matches the trigger of the first (and second) quantifier, the first quantifier is instantiated with this `k`, and that completes the proof of the two `ensures` clauses.

A `forall k | Range(k) ensures Q(k)` statement proves `Q(k)` for an arbitrary `k` that satisfies `Range(k)`. In logic, this rule is knows as *universal introduction*. After the `forall` statement, the proving context gets to assume the condition `forall k :: Range(k) ==> Q(k)`. For the `forall` statement above, that formula is the same as in your third assertion, which lets the verifier prove it. In more detail, take a look at the trigger of the `forall` statement. It is the expression `2 * k`. Thus, the verifier will instantiate this quantifier with any `X` that appears in an expression of the form `2 * X` in the proof context. Since `*` is a common operator, there may be a lot of such expressions; luckily, in your example, there are not too many and the proof goes through quickly.

### Using more distinguished names

A reason that your third assertion is more difficult to prove is that it mostly contains built-in operators, like `&&` and `<=` and `-`. Those operators are not particularly "distinguished", and they are not used in triggers. In fact, the `*` is often avoided in triggers, too, unless there's not much choice. (For example, `2 * k` was not chosen as a trigger in the first two quantifiers in your example, because `heap_condition(p_a, k, m)` looked like a better trigger to Dafny. But in the `forall` statement above, Dafny's trigger-selection machinery had to settle on `2 * k`.) You don't have to know how Dafny selects triggers, but it can be useful to inspect what triggers are chosen, which you do by hover text.

If the formulas in your examples were more distinguished in some way, then the triggers chosen may be different. You can do this by introducing some names. For example, using

```
predicate A(start: int, m: int, k: int, p_i: int, i: int) {
  start <= k <= m && k != p_i && k != i && 2*k+1 <= m
}

predicate C(k: int, m: int, p_a: seq<int>, c: nat)
  requires 1 <= k && m <= |p_a|
{
  2*k+c <= m ==> p_a[k-1] >= p_a[2*k+c-1]
}
```

you can write your 3 assertions as

```
  assert forall k: int :: A(start, m, k, p_i, i) ==>
    (heap_condition(p_a, k, m) <==> C(k, m, p_a, 0) && C(k, m, p_a, 1));
  assert forall k: int :: A(start, m, k, p_i, i) ==>
    heap_condition(p_a, k, m);
  assert forall k: int :: A(start, m, k, p_i, i) ==>
    C(k, m, p_a, 0) && C(k, m, p_a, 1);
```

In this case, Dafny can prove the third assertion from the first two without any further help. Why? Let's look at the triggers. Both the first and second quantifiers include `A(start, m, k, p_i, i)` in their triggers. Since the condition in the third assertion does too, the verifier is already led to believe that the first two assertions will be useful, so it will instantiate them with `k` and that finishes the proof.

I introduced both `A` and `C`, but the example would go through even if you just introduced one of them (either one). Try it and look at the triggers.

Having to introduce names for all subexpressions would be annoying. But in the case above, introducing the predicate `A` (but perhaps with a nicer name like `Range`) may, in addition to leading to more automatic proofs, be easier to read for a human.